# Convenience functions for operators in Java 8?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

In Python, if I want to do a fold over the operation xor, I can write:

```
reduce(operator.xor, my_things, 0)
```

rather than the more cumbersome

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x^y, my_things, 0)
```

Is there anything like this in the new Java 8 functional features? e.g. to write something like this

```
myThings.reduce(0, Integer::xor)
```

rather than

```
myThings.reduce(0, (x, y) -> x ^ y)
```

Comment: What’s the big advantage of writing `Integer::xor` over `(x,y) -> x^y`?

Comment: @Holger Nothing in particular, it's just more concise, and it's something that's supported by many languages (Python, Ruby, Haskell, SML, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`Integer#sum(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#sum-int-int-) which is used as you suggest in the package private [`IntPipeline`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/IntPipeline.java#IntPipeline.sum%28%29), but no similar methods for other numerical operators.

```
@Override
public final int sum() {
    return reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

You can define them yourself.

Comment: There are also `Integer.max` and `Integer.min`, so it provides exactly the three methods which you don’t need to pass to `reduce` as `IntStream` already has `sum()`, `min()`, and `max()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `::` method reference operator on any static or instance method in place of a functional interface (lambda). I don't think there is one for Integer.